# Redshift Create View without Base Table

Tags: amazon-redshift, ddl, sql-view

I am trying to create Views in our Amazon Redshift. The problem is, some of the base tables are not yet created by my partner, so I would like to create the views without them.

I found in this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/666034?start=0&tstart=0) that Oracle has a `FORCE` keyword to solve this issue. However, it seems Redshift does not have it (or I am using it wrong).

`CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ....` returns a syntax error.

How can I create my Views without the base tables?

Comment: Please remove PostgreSQL from your title as it is completely different to Redshift for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your view "WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING".

This will create a "late binding view" which doesn't check the underlying database objects, such as tables and other views.

Please see AWS documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html